# Vuetify v-data-table double click event does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a v-data-table.

According to [official library](https://vuetifyjs.com/ja/components/data-tables/), it has a `dblclick:row` event.

I tried to use it, but doesn't work.

(click:row event works fine.)

vuetify version is latest `vuetify@2.3.8`.

how can I use double click event in v-data-table?

here is my code sample.

(sorry for didn't write full code. I added. )

```
 <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
          <v-data-table
          :items="items"
          :headers="headers"
          dense
          v-model="selected"
          hide-default-footer
          @click:row="clickRow"
          @dblclick:row="dblclickRow"
        >
        </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
        selected: [],   
        headers: [
              {
                text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
                align: "start",
                sortable: false,
                value: "name"
              },
              { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
              { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
              { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
              { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
              { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" }
            ],
            items: [
              {
                name: "Frozen Yogurt",
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                iron: "1%"
              },
              {
                name: "Ice cream sandwich",
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: "1%"
              },
              {
                name: "Eclair",
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 23,
                protein: 6.0,
                iron: "7%"
              },
              {
                name: "Cupcake",
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                carbs: 67,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: "8%"
              },
              {
                name: "Gingerbread",
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 49,
                protein: 3.9,
                iron: "16%"
              },
              {
                name: "Jelly bean",
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                carbs: 94,
                protein: 0.0,
                iron: "0%"
              }
            ],
selected:[]
      }),
    
      methods: {
            dblclickRow(){
              console.log("rowDoubleClicked");
            },
            clickRow(){
            //  console.log("rowClicked");
            }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Your code should work perfectly fine (if in data you have also `selected`): https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/vYGLgGV?editors=1010 Please provide a [mcve]. Also, when writing a question, make sure that the code you are presenting actually reproduces the issue, you can do it by for example testing in a codepen.

Comment: sorry for I didn't write full code. added and tested in a codepen.

Comment: So if you tested your codepen, it should work: https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/vYGLgGV?editors=1010 Also you are missing `selected` from `data`, but seems it works even without defining that, just throwing error in console, but you should see it. It might have to do with the issue (??) Add `selected`.

Comment: in my pen, it seems don't work:https://codepen.io/hayato38/pen/BaKjWpp?editors=1011

add `selected`, but there is no change.

Comment: You said that you are using vuetify `vuetify@2.3.8`, the codepen you gave, is using `2.0.10`. If you update the version, it works.

Comment: excuse me , where can I update vuetify version in pen?

Comment: Click on "settings", then choose "JS" in the modal that opens, and see the cdn version of vuetify. Update it to 2.3.8.

Comment: It works. Thanks.  it seems trouble in my project is as same as this.
when I check vuetify version  by `npm info vuetify`, it was `vuetify@2.3.8`,
but in package.json, it was `"vuetify": "^2.2.11"`.
It seems cause.

Comment: Yes, that would be the cause. It should work when you update :)

Comment: @AJT82 heyho, I saw your codepan and that it worked in your codepen - but for some reason the v-data-table that I have isn't even firing the dlbClick event (checked with the vue debugger). Do you have any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score -2):

Your functions should be under methods. See this link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers.

The event is not reaching your function

Comment: this answer makes no sense what so ever.